# How to change the gravity with a click

Tags: c#, unity, 2d, physics, unityscript

How to change the gravity of a ball upward with a click
Then change it again downward with another click
And so on
In unity

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D-gravity.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void ReverseGravity()
{
     Physics2D.gravity = new Vector3(0, -1.0F, 0);
}

void ApplyGravity()
{
     Physics2D.gravity = new Vector3(0, 1.0F, 0);
}
//if you are not using 2D then use Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, 1.0F, 0);
//you could also  use Rigidbody AddForce to get your desired effect without changing any physics.
//you can set up a bool normalGravity and use something like this in a LateUpdate()
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            if (normalGravity)
            {
                normalGravity = false;
                ReverseGravity();
            }
            else
            { 
                normalGravity = true;
                ApplyGravity();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Physics.gravity *= -1.0f; // :P
```